# Ajax doesn't work with Rails3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I want Follow button that changes to Un-Follow when its clicked.
But when it submits form, it doesn't do any at all.
Why?

My codes are like these

-----Action(users_controller.rb)-----

```
 def set_follow
   friend = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
   if f = Friendship.find(:first, :conditions => { :user_id => current_user.id, :friend_id => friend.id})

     f.destroy
     flash[:notice] = "Now added to follow list"
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to set_follow }
       format.js
     end
     #redirect_to :back
   else
     Friendship.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :friend_id => friend.id)
     flash[:error] = "Now deleted from follow list"
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to set_follow }
       format.js
     end
     #redirect_to :back
   end
end
```

-----Form(users/index.html.erb)-----

```
<div id="follow_status">
   <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.friends.find_by_id(user.id) %>
     <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-remove icon-white"></i> ') + 'Un-Follow', follow_user_path(user.username), :class => 'btn', remote: true %>
   <% elsif current_user != user %>
     <%= link_to sanitize('<i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> ') + 'Follow', follow_user_path(user.username), :class => 'btn btn-primary', remote: true %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

-----JS View(set_follow.js.erb)-----

```
$("#follow_status").html("<%= escape_javascript(render f) %>");
```

Comment: @Jon Day Thanks for edit!I was trying to fix, too :)

Comment: no probs needed to, to try and solve the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a different method but I would just do this with JQuery

```
$('.btn').click( function() {
    if( $('.btn').html() == 'Follow') {
        $('.btn').html('Unfollow');
    }
    else if( $('.btn').html() == 'Unfollow') {
        $('.btn').html('Follow');
    }

});
```

​
This is just a bit of an example how you could do it. You would probably want to use a more specific chain of classes in the jquery

Comment: Thanks for answer. But in your case, it seems that doesn't concern about real value of friendship flag:(